# A graph with max 5 nodes that fulfils the folowing requirements

Tags: graph-theory

It should contain exactly four cycles and these should all have length 4;
ii) Your graph should contain a node which has degree 3;
iii) Your graph should contain a subgraph which is a tree that has a depth of 3 and
which has two nodes at level 2.
iv) Your graph should contain the smallest number of nodes possible given the
constraints above.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, I'm having trouble seeing the point of iv, as i and especially iii seems to require the maximum of 5 nodes anyways.

Comment: I have tried (a,b) (b,c) (b,d) (b,e) (c,e) (e,b) , but I either get 3 cycles or 6 if I make any more edges and cannot get them to be exactly 4 of length 4.

Comment: Are you allowed to have parallel edges?

Comment: What is depth of a tree?

Comment: @mathnoob The *depth* (or *height*) of a tree is the maximum depth of any node in the tree; in other words, it is the length of the longest path from the root to any node.

Comment: @mathnoob and it starts from 0 (the root node), and I think you are allowed to have parallel edges.

Comment: So then I assume that cycles created by parallel edges dosen't count as they are cycles of length 2.

Comment: @mathnoob yes indeed

Answer (score 2):

Here is a graph that satisfy the conditions I think:
[image]